# Response personalization

Tags: c#, rest, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

This is a general design question.

I'm building a REST API on NET Core 2.0, to interact with, and Angular project front end.
I have a grid, that need to paginate, sort, and filter on server side.
This is my server code for the GET method involved:

```
[HttpGet]                
public IActionResult Get(int activos=1, string source="", int idarticulo = -1, string filtro = "", string ordenar = "", int ordenarsentido = 1, int registroinic = -1, int registros = -1)
{
    // Check for a valid Token 
    if (!_validation.ValidarToken(User)) return Unauthorized();

    IArticulosService articulosService = new ArticulosService(_validation.sConnectionString, _validation.sEmpresa);

    try
    {
        return Ok(articulosService.ListarVista(activos, filtro, ordenar, ordenarsentido, registroinic, registros));                        
    }
    catch (QueryFormatException ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

This all works great. The problem comes when I try to persolize JSON response.

`ListarVista()` function returns an array of a class that represent a database view. It has something like 20 fields. Now I need users to choose which fields to represent on the grid, and in which order.

I can solve this by creating another method to return columns to be rendered, but my Get method still return all 20 fields on each call with is not efficient.
Also I need to export all the grid content to Excel. If I use the same method I will get all 20 fields again.

So my question is **which options do I have to personalize JSON Response on server side**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [this one](https://blog.rsuter.com/advanced-newtonsoft-json-dynamically-rename-or-ignore-properties-without-changing-the-serialized-class/) should help you.

In this scenario you can create JsonSerializationSettings per object and even per user if you identify in which user context your method is called

Comment: I'll look into it. Thank you